# Is it possible to test wasm-pack generated webassembly from a javascript context?

Tags: javascript, rust, automated-tests, wasm-pack

I have a rust + wasm project like this:

```
wasm-pack-example/
  pkg/
    .gitignore
    package.json
    wasm_pack_example.d.ts
    wasm_pack_example.js
    wasm_pack_example_bg.d.ts
    wasm_pack_example_bg.js
    wasm_pack_example_bg.wasm
  src/
    lib.rs
  Cargo.toml
```

The contents of `pkg` get built when I run `wasm-pack build`.

The emitted js files aren't simple pass-throughs of the public rust functions - wasm-pack adds some logic to them. It looks mostly like memory management wrappers over the public rust functions.

What I really want to do at this point in my project is to write automated tests against the js interface to the emitted wasm. This is what my app does, and this is what I need to test. I'm happy using any testing framework (I've been doing a lot of this experimentation with jest).

I've tried numerous guides and tools to do this, including https://github.com/DrSensor/rs-jest, which was promising, but lacks the ability to test the specific js interface produced by wasm-pack. Also, it seems to lack what's needed by my particular lib, perhaps in the particular way I'm using wasm_bindgen. When instantiating the WebAssembly according to rs-jest's, I'd see `TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Imports argument must be present and must be an object`, and if I passed an empty object to the instantiation, I'd see `TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="__wbindgen_placeholder__" error: module is not an object or function`.

I also tried for a while to simulate the particular way wasm might be fetched and instantiated by the browser using JsDom. I produced an index.html file that loaded the wasm-pack js files via a script tag, then I created a JsDom instance using that index.html file. It properly tried to fetch the wasm from an import in the js (which required me to add my own `fetch` implementation to the JsDom instance's window, serving back the wasm file from the filesystem), but then choked halfway down the js file because `module.require` is not a function. I was unable to make any progress past that.

Anyway, this is just to show that I haven't been able to find any solution for this. Has anybody out there been able to write automated tests against the js interfaces produced by wasm-pack?

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same situation. I use wasm-pack and Jest, but not rs-jest. I just want to write Jest tests against the wasm-pack-generated JavaScript package.

I couldn't get my tests to work with Jest `testEnvironment: "jsdom"` and `wasm-pack build`: Jest would complain that it *cannot find module 'foo_wasm'* on `import * as wasm from "foo_wasm";`.

However, setting `testEnvironment: "node"` in jest.config.ts and running `wasm-pack build --target nodejs` worked for me!

However, I really do need `--target bundler` for my web app. So I run wasm-pack twice:

```bash
wasm-pack build --target bundler --out-dir pkg  # (the defaults)
wasm-pack build --target nodejs --out-dir pkg_node
```

Then in my package.json I point to the bundler/web bindings:

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "foo_wasm": "file:../wasm/foo/pkg",
  }
}
```

And in jest.config.ts I override it with the node bindings:

```
export default {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    foo_wasm: "<rootDir>/../wasm/foo/pkg_node",
  },
};
```

Then in my tests I can just `import * as wasm from "foo_wasm";`.

See [this wasm-pack issue](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack/issues/313) which would add `--target all` so we wouldn't have to run wasm-pack twice.